Calculate the sum of all the different real roots of the equation
Calculate the sum of all the different real roots of the equation $x^{2016} + (x-1)^{2016} = 2016$.
Obviously, first you need to consider the problem for a simpler case: $x^2+(x-1)^2 = 2$
In this case, we get the sum of the roots equal to 1
It seems that for the original task as well the answer should be $1$, but how to come to a solution?

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed. This is not a homework service.

Hint: use symmetry.

The polynomial is invariant under $x \mapsto 1-x$. If $\alpha$ is a real root, so does $1 - \alpha$. The question comes down to 1) showing $\frac12$ isn't a root 2) the polynomial cannot have more than 2 real roots....

The function $f(x)=x^{2n}+(x-1)^{2n}$ is increasing for $x\ge 1$ and $f(1)=1.$

The reasoning is elementary. No derivatives are used.
We are going to show that there are exactly two real roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that $x_1+x_2=1.$ Let $$f(x)=x^{2016}+(x-1)^{2016}-2016$$ For $0\le x\le 1$ we have $f(x)<2-2016<0.$  Moreover $f(s(x))=f(x)$ where $s(x)=1-x.$ We have
$$s([\textstyle 1,\infty ))= (-\infty,0]$$
Thus it suffices to show that $f(x)$ has a unique root in $[1,\infty).$
This would imply that $x_2=s(x_1)=1-x_1$ is the unique root in $(-\infty,0].$
Clearly the function $f(x)$ is increasing in $[1,\infty).$ Therefore there is exactly one root $x_1$  in $[1,\infty),$ as desired.
Summarizing there are exactly two real roots $x_1>1$ and $x_2<0$ related by $x_2=1-x_1.$ Their sum is equal $1.$

Hint
Following on from achille lui's hint in the comments, if $\ f(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}x^{2016}+(x-1)^{2016}\ ,$ then
$$
f''(x)\ge0,f''\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)>0\
$$
so $\ f\ $ is convex, and $\ f'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0\ ,$ so $\ f'(x)<0 $ for $\ x<\frac{1}{2}\ $ and $\ f'(x)>0\ $ for $\ x>\frac{1}{2}\ .$ Therefore, $\ f(x)\ $ is strictly decreasing for $\ x<\frac{1}{2}\ ,$ strictly increasing for $\ x>\frac{1}{2}\ $ and has a unique minumum at $\ x=\frac{1}{2}\ $ with $\ f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{2015}}\ .$ What can you conclude from that about the number of real roots of $\ f(x)=2016\ ?$
